# jQuery Circle Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to have a universe type menu, where there is a main item in the center, and "X" amount of items around it. (ie: sun with planets).

I have searched high and low for an example, and all of the search results points to using css, but this requires manually figuring out the position of the items.

How can I create a menu like this where I can dynamically add items?

I am sure there is some jQuery / javascript example somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out jQuery Radmenu - http://tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin

Comment: glad to help!.. if you want, feel free to shoot a link over when you're done.. i'm starting to add links of examples that are in the wild. and of course, let me know if you think the plugin can be improved in any way.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Did you try searching for pie menus? There are a couple of jQuery Plugins:

- [jQuery - Pie Menu](http://www.heysaturdaysun.com/pie/)
- [jQuery Canvas Pie Menu](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/piemenu)

Answer (score 1):

I've just done a hell of lot of googling for you - but couldn't find anything either.

So, the answer must be - write it for yourself (see, that's fun!).
I found [this great resource](http://cs.unc.edu/~mcmillan/comp136/Lecture7/circle.html) to help out. It's not JavaScript, but the code could easily be rewritten to help drawing the invisible circle needed to do the trick.

Some sin/cos stuff will probably also be needed - to determine where on the circle your menu points should be, dynamically. It's unfortunately not just as simple as saying `360/numberOfMenus` ;-)

I hope this helps you out. Sometimes, the answer is that you have to do it yourself :D

Comment: thanx, appreciate all the effort. i was contemplating doing it in silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread too late, because I also built one. You can find it here: http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/hp/circulate/index.html

It is a jQuery plugin, very small, that positions li items in a circle.